# Can you do a regex in the select statement on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can see you can do like in the where clause, but can you do a regex in a select statement? I have rows with something like following:

/sites/xxxx-588-xxxxxxxx/Delte dokumenter/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/file.pdf

And I need to do a select that always get the value between /sites/ and after the next /. So here it would be xxxx-588-xxxxxxxx. So if you could so something like select regex(columnname, 'my regex') from table .... Is that possible?

Comment: SQL Server / T-SQL has limited pattern-matching support, but does not support full-on regular-expressions (without using SQL-CLR). The only alternative is to use a custom scalar UDF.

Comment: Why not select the entire value and perform the regex in your application code? Do you need to use the regex's matched groups' values directly in another query?

Comment: You have sufficient rep to know that you should search the internet first - and doing so would have found many discussions about what regex support is provided in tsql.

Comment: I'm thinking "Green Eggs and Ham":  I will not support regex in the SELECT.  I will not support regex in the WHERE.  I will not support them here or there!  I am SQL Server.  SQL Server I am.  (sincere apologies to Dr. Seuss)

Comment: We can easily enough handle this requirement using `CHARINDEX` (though it leads to some ugly code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `CHARINDEX` here:

```
SELECT
    path,
    SUBSTRING(path,
              CHARINDEX('/sites/', path) + 7,
              CHARINDEX('/', path, CHARINDEX('/sites/', path) + 7) -
                  CHARINDEX('/sites/', path) - 7) AS component
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The idea here is to take the following substring:

```
/sites/xxxx-588-xxxxxxxx/Delte dokumenter/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/file.pdf
       ^    ...        ^
```

We do this using `CHARINDEX` by finding the position of `/sites/`, and then also finding the occurrence of the next `/` after `/sites`.